# Find object through search box with Cesium Js

Tags: point, cesium, search, find

I am using Cesium and I would like to do a very simple operation. I would like to find an object which I created by typing its name in the search bar on the top right corner.
Let's consider for example the `Points` tutorial present in `Sandcastle`:

```
function addPoint() {
   Sandcastle.declare(addPoint);

   viewer.entities.add({
       position : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-75.59777, 40.03883),
       name : 'POINT NAME'
       point : {
           pixelSize : 10,
           color : Cesium.Color.YELLOW
       }
   });
}
```

If I type `POINT NAME` in the search bar I do not get any result. How can I find the point using the search bar?

[image]

Comment: If anyone comes here looking for an answer, you can find it here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44372068/find-object-through-search-box-with-cesium-js